# repositories.cfg could not be loaded on linux for Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, linux-mint

Installing NativeScript showed some problems when installing the following: all packages for the Android SDK Platform 25, Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2 or later, Android Support Repository, Google Repository and any other SDKs that you may need.

```
command: sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;25.0.2" "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository"

$ sudo $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "tools" "platform-tools" "platforms;
> android-25" "build-tools;
> 25.0.2" "extras;
> android;
> m2repository" "extras;
> google;
> m2repository"
Warning: File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Warning: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!
Warning: Failed to find package tools
```

I am stuck on this. Can someone lend me a hand?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using strace:

```
$ strace -e trace=network -y -s 256 -f -o strace.log tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

I found a reference to "Equifax Secure Certificate Authority" in strace.log coming from IP address `172.217.23.46`, which according to `whois` belongs to google.

Then using openssl to check the certificate:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 172.217.23.46:443
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
```

<strike>This Equifax certificate was revoked according to https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository/crls/ so this is up to google to replace the certificate.</strike>
Equifax appears to be no longer trusted by Ubuntu 16.04 (the system I'm testing this on).

I have contacted google about this.

Edit: Google responded with "Won't fix".